# How do I map drive letter to a local path in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, is it possible to map a drive letter to a local path ?

So for example map `x:\` to `c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\`

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`subst`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx):

> `subst x: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\`

or [`New-PSDrive`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx):

> `New-PSDrive -Name x -PSProvider FileSystem -Root c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\`

Comment: I think PSDrives are only visible from inside the PowerShell session and not external programs.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - Good point. Still worth showing how to use if whatever problem being solved is within that PS session. I also noticed the same applies to `subst`.

Answer (score 4):

The following statement will also work (and it only uses native powershell cmdlets):

```
New-PsDrive -Name [DRIVELETTER] -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\localhost\C$\[PATH]" -Persist
```